# Why does the same amount of current flow through both resistors after opening the switch S?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, electromagnetic-induction, inductance

[image]
Why does the same amount of current flow through both resistors after opening the switch S?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the switch is open the branch which includes the battery can be taken away as current in the static case flows only in a closed loop and therefore you’ll end up only with the right loop including the resistors and the inductor with inductance $L$.